# How to upgrade a project to .NET Core 3.1.18

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I'm not sure if it's possible or not, the target framework in project properties is .NET Core 3.1

I also installed version 3.1.18 and upgraded all related Nuget packages to 3.1.18

is there a way to indicate that the project is using .NET Core 3.1.18? (or is it using the latest by default)

Comment: Generally, you don't need to. Things will use the latest runtime you have installed. By default, the latest 3.1.x version will be used. If that's not available, the latest 3.x version will be used. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking too.

Comment: It depends only to the framework you've installed on your target system. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using .NET Core 3.1 in VS 2019, there is no option to tell the project to use a specific framework version (for example - 3.1.16 or 3.1.18), it will simply use the latest installed version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need only to indicate the major release as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-versions

Then it depends on your target output, like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-ios14.0</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>13.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion> (minimum os platform version)
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

or:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
    <Description>Sample project that targets multiple TFMs</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

If you read the documentation you see:
`netcoreapp3.1`

Then the project will be upgraded at the latest version available on target system.
If you have installed version 3.1.18 on your target system that version will be used.
The nuget packages are, instead, related of your configured nuget sources.
If you have configured your system with the standard sources, the build system or VS will download the version declaration json file from the sources. This file contains the latest stable (or preview, in case you selected it) version number, so the build system will use this file to verify the version number of the package you indicated.
If the package number is compatible with your target framework that package will be downloaded from the related source.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking specifically for .NET Core 3.x

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I've added the specific information for 3.1 and obviously is valid for ALL the 3.1.x subversion, as described by Microsoft.